# /wp-admin/post.php shows 404 template on submit

Tags: templates, plugins, 404-error

When I publish or save a post, I see the 404 error page from my template. This happens with posts and WooCommerce products.

I'm using the Twenty Twelve theme, and I have the following plugins activated: WooCommerce, Limit Login Attempts, Google Analyticator.

I just installed Wordpress yesterday.

Comment: Did you try to disable all your plugins to see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: @s1lv3r Yes it does. It's weird because the template shouldn't show at ./wp-admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain didn't have www. in the wordpress settings. Adding this worked. No idea what the problem was exactly, but this solved it.

Edit: Not yet fixed. It was mod_security which blocked 'Wordpress.com.' (I'm at Namecheap which uses mod_security)